# In tableau, I have a bar chart with ten categories. I want to put 4 lowest categories together in an other category.

Tags: tableau-api

I think this is a pretty basic function but nothing I've seen has worked as I want it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried creating a group? https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/sortgroup_groups_creating.html